# "Liquid" tiles scroll with CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, css, html, layout, markup

I am tasked to implement a web page element that is a group of tiles that should scroll smoothly on touch devices, and support traditional scrolling via buttons in a web page:

[image: designExample]

On tablet, when a user scrolls the portfolio tiles, they should be scrolling instead of an entire page.

How can this be achieved with respect to layout/markup? Maybe you can advise an example tutorial on how similar has been implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would set a fixed height to the tiles container, and style it with: `overflow: scroll` and a bit of JS as described in the links below.

For more info on mobile specific touch scrolling, check-out:

http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4

http://blog.joelambert.co.uk/2011/10/14/a-fix-for-ios5-overflow-scrolling-scrollfix-js/

http://johanbrook.com/browsers/native-momentum-scrolling-ios-5/

Comment: Yep, first link is exactly what I needed. Thank you.